# Random Username and password failures azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Im trying to move data from an on-prem oracle database to an azure sql server instance with a self hosted IR since after the recent update(i think that was the cause) i keep getting random Invalid User name and Password on the copy activities.

Is there anyway to rollback the update or any ideas on how can i fix this ?

[image: Run 1]
[image: Run2]

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this starting on October 19 2018 with usernames that have underscores in them. We switched to using a username without underscores and that allowed us to make consistent connections from DataFactory.